# Git compare files between branches

Tags: git, file, compare

I have 2 branches merged into one another. On the other hand in one branch there are "extra" files shown. So branch A has 2 files, branch B has 3 files. If I do a pull, all I get is "Already up-to-date", which would mean the branches are the same. They are not though.
How can I see the files that are present in one branch, but not in the other? `Git diff <local branch> <remote branch>` is not ideal as it shows me all the code. I would only need the filenames, so I can delete that extra file. Obviously there are more than one file, and I need to find how many.

Answer (score 2):

```
git diff --name-only master <your_branch>
```

will list changed files on  compared to `master` branch.

Comment: Thanks guys, git diff --name-only master <your_branch> seems to do the job well. I meanwhile found a way to do the same with Beyond Compare, as I had it on my pc. git difftool --dir-diff <your branch> <master> does the job too. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the git log or git diff (ill explain in details):

#### git log

```
git log ^branch_a branch_b 
git log branch_a ^branch_b
```

This will simulate pull/push

### git diff

```
git diff branch_a..branch_b
git diff branch_a...branch_b
```